# Show that $lim_{n→∞} (r^{(n+1)^{2}}-r^{n^{2}})∑_{m=n+2}^{∞}v_{m}r^{-m²}<+∞$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $r>4$ be a positive integer. Let $0<v_{m}<r^{m},m≥3$ be an increasing and divergent sequence. Let $n≥3$.

My **question** is: Show that $$lim_{n→∞} (r^{(n+1)^{2}}-r^{n^{2}})∑_{m=n+2}^{∞}v_{m}r^{-m²}<+∞$$

I am not able to find the good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u_n$ your expression. Put $\displaystyle w_n=r^{(n+1)^2}\sum_{m\geq n+2}\frac{r^m}{r^{m^2}}$ Then obviously $u_n\leq w_n$. Now put $m=n+2+j$. Then we have
$$m^2-m=(n+1)^2+n(2j+1)+j^2+3j+1$$
Hence $$w_n= \sum_{j\geq 0}\frac{1}{r^{(n(2j+1)+j^2+3j+1}}\leq \sum_{j\geq 0}\frac{1}{r^{j^2+3j+1}}=M$$

Hence $u_n$ is bounded.

Comment: Furthermore, $w_n\leqslant\sum\limits_{j\geqslant0}r^{-n(2j+1)}=r^n/(r^{2n}-1)\to0$ hence $u_n\to0$.

Comment: Yes, good remark. In fact I was answering the original question, that was to show that $u_n\to +\infty$.